# Pandas Grouby Month adds Empty Rows between Dates

Tags: pandas

I start with my df and there are only two months with data.

I need to sum those months to get the total debits and credits.

```
             action  shares      debit      credit
date                                                      
2016-05-27     +   13883.000  13883.000           0
2016-05-27     -  166600.000          0  166600.000
2012-08-30     +    1428.000   1428.000           0
2012-08-30     -   10000.000          0   10000.000
2012-08-27     +   55085.000  55085.000           0
2012-08-27     -  385600.000          0  385600.000
```

So I thought I would do a groupby Month

```
g = df.groupby ( pd.Grouper ( freq = 'M' ) ).sum ()[["debit", "credit"]]
```

But this gives me all the empty months and not just the two months.

```
                    debit      credit
    date                             
    2012-08-31  56513.000  395600.000
    2012-09-30          0           0
    2012-10-31          0           0
    2012-11-30          0           0
    ....
    2016-04-30          0           0
    2016-05-31  13883.000  166600.000
```

How can I drop all the empty rows or is there a better way to sum the two months with the data?

Thanks.

Comment: `g = g[g.debit != 0]`?

Comment: that does work but there are more valuable than I showed.  think this is the most simple answer though?  was thing maybe I could add something to the Groupby to eliminate the non-data?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `g = g[(g.debit != 0) & (g.credit != 0)]` is probably the simplest answer, but to answer specifically what you're asking, I would truncate the dates to the month value.

I'm assuming they're strings. If they're `datetime` objects the logic is similar; you just need to put a `1` in the `day` part.

```
def trunc_to_month(x):
    y = x.split('-')
    return '-'.join(y[0], y[1], '1')

df['date_month'] = df.date.apply(trunc_to_month)
```

Then just do the same groupby but with `date_month` instead of `date`.